# How to stream Audio with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, streaming, audio-streaming

I would like to display the names of about 15 songs in an unordered list, simple css display, nothing fancy - I can do this. I would then like to add a triangle image (play button) next to each filename, which when pressed plays the audio file and also toggles with a square image (stop button) which when pressed stops the audio file.

I would also like each 'play' button to unplay/stop all the other files before it starts. To avoid clashing of one song over the top of another.

The plan is to have the audio 'stream' from uploaded files rather than download. I would prefer they just play without opening in an external player and not using a jquery plugin etc. I'm hoping that it might be possible to prevent these files from being downloaded by disable right click 'save as' on the play buttons etc.

I have a basic knowledge of Jquery, Javascript and so using either of those would be great. The display is very minimal and simple, hopefully there is a simple pure jquery approach to compliment this with the functionality.

If anybody can point me in the right direction then I would be very grateful.

Many thanks

Comment: It is impossible to prevent someone from downloading the songs using just javascript.

Comment: Hi Joe, googling seems to be given me a lot of results but they are all very plugin focused, jquery players etc, I was hoping there might be a more simple solution in pure code rather than using the code of a whole jquery plugin with all the features. If you are having results returned other than plugin based then would love to know the link. Cheers. I know the code is wrong but I'm looking for something in jquery like: `'#playBtn'.click function { 'audio src'.playaudio() } etc`

Comment: Check out [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/mp3-player-button/).

Comment: Thanks idbehold, that's a great reference. I'll investigate it further and see if I can extend it (if needed) to do what I need. Looks like a great starting point though. cheers